# install redmine on linux entreprise server

Tags: rubygems

Actually am developing a Redmine in my Server , and i need to get bundler.
Currently i'm following some steps to set my Redmine from this tutorial (www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) , and as you can see they ask first to get ruby environment and all the other dependencies(Gems,gcc) ,then they ask to install Bundler and here where i'm stuck because i cannot run (gem install bundler) in my server because i can’t connect to internet from it.
So please can you help me with an alternative to get bundler.
Thank you for your cooperation .

Answer (score 0):

You can download [bundler rubygem](http://rubygems.org/downloads/bundler-1.7.9.gem) directly,  copy it to your server and install it via `gem install bundler` command in same folder as downloaded file.

But probably you will be missing internet connection to do `bundle install` after it will be installed anyway.

*Maybe you should ask someone to package Redmine for your fits or setup local rubygems mirror.*

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to build a standalone package on a different machine that *does* have an internet connection, using `bundle install --deployment --standalone`.

This will download and install all of the gems to a directory inside of the redmine root directory, and generate a file setting up the load path so that you won't need Bundler installed on the server at runtime.

You'll then need to modify the code to avoid calling Bundler on startup, and instead require the generated `bundle/bundler/setup.rb` file.

There are more details on this at http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/03/faster-test-boot-times-with-bundler-standalone

Then, you would copy this modified redmine directory onto your server.

Alternatively, you could install an existing redmine binary package on your server using rpm, apt, or equivalent. The details of this depend on the specific server OS you're using.

Comment: hi thanks for your help , i installed redmine in another machine , an i took all the gem that i installed in the second machine and i put theme in the server and buy using the command that you gave me (bundle install --standalone)it installed al the the necessary gems that i required in the Gemfile , thank you so much guys